# Git update local files with manual merge

Tags: git, github

I would like to update all my local files with latest update from remote repository and manually resolve conflict without committing my changes to repository.  I tried run for pull but it was aborted due to I have changes of local files which requested me to do commit.  Can advice how to do this?

Comment: Why would you not want to commit? You do know that your local repository is an entirely separate entity, right?  Make a local branch or branches for your work, treat your repository as an extension of your editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a temp branch, fetch and rebase:

```
$ git checkout -b temp
$ git fetch origin master
$ git rebase origin/master
```